# While trying to drop 10000 tables in one short in postgres sql getting error out of shared memory increase max_locks_per_transaction

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

out of shared memory HINT: You might need to increase
max_locks_per_transaction.
We are passing input as comma separated tables table_names and trying to drop a huge
set of table

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Schema".drop_tables(table_names character varying
          RETURNS void AS
        $BODY$
        DECLARE tables text[];
        DECLARE table_name VARCHAR;
        BEGIN
        SET search_path='Schema';
        SELECT into tables string_to_array(table_names,',');
        FOREACH table_name IN ARRAY tables
        LOOP
            EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE %I', table_name);
        END LOOP;
        END;
        $BODY$
          LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
          COST 100;
        ALTER FUNCTION "Schema".drop_tables(character varying)
          OWNER TO postgres;
```

It works well when i pass 1000 tables but it throws error when i pass 10000 tables.
It just throws exception to increase the max_locks_per_transaction
What is max locks available for the function? Is there any way
to calculate the by how much we should increase the
max_locks_per_transaction value by default the value is 64.

Comment: Are you really using three different and BTW long **outdated** versions? If not, please avoid tag spam. If any, it'll give you more *negative* attention.

Comment: Postgres 9.1, 9.3 and 9.4 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `declare` starts a _block_ to declare variables. There is no need to use a separate declare block for each variable.

Comment: What happened when you followed the advice and increased `max_locks_per_transaction`?

Comment: I think what you are being told is that dropping 10000 tables at a time is not a good idea.

Comment: two things i want to know 1. is ddl statements inside a function are in a single transaction 2. Is there any formula by which number we can increase the max_locks_per_transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping a table reqires an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, all its indexes and the TOAST table and its index (if they exist). Such locks are stored in the shared memory lock table, which has room for `max_connections * max_locks_per_transaction` entries. The locks are held until the end of the transaction, and a function is always executed in a single transaction.

So if you need more than the default 6400 lock table entries to drop all your tables, either increase the parameter or distribute the action across several database transactions.

Comment: Even in this case when 6400 locks available when we try to drop 4000 tables it failed again with the exception saying to increase the max_locks_per_transactions

Comment: Then go and increase it.